# How to set fixed width to Data tables columns?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I know it's been discussed here before so i went over all the answers first but still have some problems.

I have a table with a comments column with much more text then the others....i want to set fixed size to all the columns and only for the comments column to set a different size - or just to break line - don't know yet what is the best way... hope you can help me.

I didn't manage to get this code to work :

```
   bAutoWidth: false , 
  "aoColumnDefs": [
  { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
  { "sWidth": "5%", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
  { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
  { "sWidth": "5%", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
  { "sWidth": "40%", "aTargets": [ 4 ] },
  { "sWidth": "5%", "aTargets": [ 5 ] },
  { "sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [ 6 ] }
  ],
```

Here is a sample of the project ( in production there are more columns with much more text) 
     [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jI9ArQ?p=preview)

Comment: Have a look at this link https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width

Comment: Thanks - as i mentioned - i looked over it already.

Comment: Tried using same code provided in link? is it working?

Comment: Yes, i've tried - it's the first thing that i've done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First; you need to make a small change in your css file;

```
#example > tbody > tr > td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

will be;

```
#example > tbody > tr > td {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

This change will break the line for long texts.
And if you still want to change the width of a specific column, you should use [**columnDefs**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) property of **DataTables**. Like;

```
"columnDefs": [{ "width": "200px", "targets": 3 }]
```

Modified example: **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sT1gNsNdPkTdg5cueYlR?p=preview)**

Comment: How can i set the size to be lower then 10px? all above 10 px works fine.... below 10 px - nothing is changing

Comment: It can't be lower than the header (Comments) width.